# ASP .NET - MVC 5 - Entity Framework - Code First - Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, forms-authentication

I inherited a MVC 5 project that was created with code-first approach. The project has all the classes for authentication/authorization (let's call them A/A here) (AccountController.cs, ManageController.cs, etc). It also has under the References folder all the references needed for A/A (like Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, etc), but the A/A wansn't implemented, and the web.config said:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />​
```

which I changed to:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~Account/LogIn" timeout="1880" />
```

and now it takes me to the login page etc.

Where I'm stuck is that the auto-generated A/A code refers to ApplicationDbContext (Example: in IdentityModels.cs), and the functioning part of the webapp that handles the screens where the users enter data, etc, access the DB thru VehicleDBContext.

There's a single connection to SQL Server in web.config named VehicleDBConnection, and the A/A should use this same context and connection, so in the constructor for ApplicationDbContext I set the base class to point to the connection:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=VehicleDBConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

At this point I checked the DB and there's no support for A/A, I mean no tables like dbo.AspNetUsers, etc. So if I try to create a user, an error page displays "Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'"

I tried to generate the tables for A/A as follows, but I get the error b/c there are still 2 contexts:

**PM> Enable-Migrations
More than one context type was found in the assembly**

I'd prefer to have 1 context only, but if that means a big change in the login auto-generated code, it'd be better to keep the 2 separate contexts as far as they point to the same connection.

How can I get the A/A supporting DB tables, stor procs, etc auto-generated into the existing DB, without affecting the migrations for the other application classes?

Thank you in advance,

Rick

Comment: Thank you Abdulrahman. I ended up switching to the IdentityDbContext and then using PM to enable migrations for this context and update database. This generated the authorization/authentication tables :-) Then I used PM enable-migrations to switch back to VehicleDBContext which is where most changes to the DB are likely to be needed. All worked as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have one context by making VehicleDBContext inherit from IdentityDbContext, and moving custom DbSets from ApplicationDbContext to it (if any), then updating Startup.cs accordingly.

If you would prefer to keep both contexts, use the -ContextTypeName command switch as follows:

1) `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Namespace.ApplicationDbContext`

This will create a Configuration.cs file, rename the class (or change to a different name space)

2) `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Namespace.VehicleDbContext`

Then, whenever you add a new migration for either context, specifiy configuration file with -ConfigurationTypeName:

```
Add-Migartion [NAME] -ConfigurationTypeName [Fully-qualified configration file name]
```